# Lookup Tables with EF 5.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to working with EF, but I couldn't resist the concept and now I am stuck.  I am developing a web form to replace a paper survey.  The data structure has a large number of lookup tables.  I have built EF based Data access layer (DAL).  I want to create a user control that can be passed the entity associated with the lookup table, then simply bind that entity to a dropdownlist, however, I am struggling with the reflection necessary to accomplish this.

My code is as follows:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ABC.ABC.Controls
{
    public partial class ABCQuestionSingle : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        CareDAL.ABC.Entities DAL = new CareDAL.ABC.Entities();

        private string dataTextField;
        public string DataTextField
        {
            get { return dataTextField; }
            set { dataTextField = value; }
        }

        private string dataValueField;
        public string DataValueField
        {
            get { return dataValueField; }
            set { dataValueField = value; }
        }

        private string entityName;
        public string EntityName
        {
            get { return entityName; }
            set { entityName = value; }
        }

        //I've tried this unsuccessfully!
        public List<TEntity> GetList<TEntity>(string _name)
        {
            IEnumerable<TEntity> enumerable = (IEnumerable<TEntity>)(typeof(CareDAL.NDNQI.DST_ABCEntities).GetProperty(_name).GetValue(DAL, null));
            return enumerable.ToList();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ddlResponse.DataTextField = "PrimaryReason";
            ddlResponse.DataValueField = "ReasonId";
            ddlResponse.DataSource = DAL.PrimaryReasons.ToList();
            ddlResponse.DataSource = GetList(entityName); //Obvious error, but not sure how to handle this!
            ddlResponse.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class ABCQuestionSingle : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public void LoadDropDown<T>(string valueProperty, string textProperty)
        where T : class
    {
        ddlResponse.DataTextField = textProperty;
        ddlResponse.DataValueField = valueProperty;
        ddlResponse.DataSource = new CareDAL.ABC.Entities().Set<T>();
        ddlResponse.DataBind();
    }
}
```

you can then call this method from the calling page's load event (or any other event really)

Comment: Worked perfectly.  That's going to save me a ton of time.  I'd buy you a drink if I could!